# Using an AsyncTask for querying an API everytime an EditText changes

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, retrofit

I've created an `AsyncTask` to query a REST API everytime a user inputs something in an `EditText`. This results in a horde of request being sent to the REST API when a user keeps typing. Is there any way for me to control the requests being sent? Is `AsyncTask` the best solution here? What are my other options?

Code as follows:

```
private AsyncTask<Object, Object, Response> searchTask;

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    this.search(s.getText().toString());
}

public void search(final String q) {

    if (searchTask != null) {
        searchTask.cancel(true);
    }

    searchTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Response>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Transaction> doInBackground(Object... params) {
            return retrofitService.findPerson(token, q);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            // do stuff here with the response
        }

    };
    searchTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: have you tried search task on "IME_ACTION_DONE"?

Comment: for a quick fix, if you are trying to make an auto complete, you can just make your api call for first letter of input and for other input changes you can search in your result list of api call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your method of execution use volley library. here is the link http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html